# Why does a single threaded operationg takes 3 times longer than no threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, time, cpu

I'm testing concurrency in Java, my objective is to determine if having multiple threads is actually beneficial, however, I'm getting results that don't add up. I'm trying to optimize a factorial function, for this particular test I'm using 1e9! and I want the result modulo 1e9+7 so that it does not overflow. Firstly, I divided the number based on number_of_threads and assign to each thread their work respectively. I then do it normally and compare the times I get. It seems that when number_of_threads = 4, I get better results than the version without threads, which makes sense since my CPU has 4 cores. As expected, any number of threads greater than 4 has slower time compared to only 4. However, when doing it with less than 4 threads the results become way to big, for instance, with 1 threads I expect it to last the same as doing it without a thread + overhead. Without thread I get 6.2 seconds and 19.3 with 1 thread, which is way too much of a difference for it to be just the overhead.

To test why, I put some counter on the run method and it seems like, sometimes, the execution of only 1 cycle of the for inside of it takes more than a millisecond, and it shouldn't since it's just two operations plus the timer.

```
public class Calc implements Runnable{
    long min, max, mod, res;
    Res r;
    public Calc(long min, long max, long mod, Res r) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.mod = mod;
        res = 1;
        this.r = r;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(long i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            res *= i;
            res %= mod;
        }
        r.addup(res);
    }
}

public class Res{
    long result;
    long mod;
    public Res(long mod) {
        result = 1;
        this.mod = mod;
    }
    public synchronized void addup(long add) {
        result *= add;
        result %= mod;
    }
    public long getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long factorial = 1000000000L;
        final long modulo = 1000000007L;
        Res res = new Res(modulo);
        int number_of_threads = 1;
        Thread[] c = new Thread[number_of_threads];
        long min = 1, max = factorial/(long)number_of_threads;
        long cant = max;
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; i++) {
            if((long)i < (factorial % number_of_threads))max++;
            c[i] = new Thread(new Calc(min, max, modulo, res));
            c[i].start();
            min = max +1;
            max += cant;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; i++) {
            try {
                c[i].join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res.getResult());
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println((double)totalTime/1000000000L);
    }
}
```

When number_of_threads = 1 I get 19.3 seconds. When number_of_threads = 2 I get 10.1 seconds. When number_of_threads = 3 I get 7.1 seconds. When number_of_threads = 4 I get 5.4 seconds. And when doing it without threads I get 6.2 seconds (I calculate the time on this one with the same method)

There shouldn't be that much difference between only 1 thread and no threads, and for 2 and 3 threads it should be faster than no thread. Why is that and is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Edit: Adding without thread version

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long factorial = 1000000000L;
        final long modulo = 1000000007L;

        long res = 1;
        for(long i = 1; i <= factorial; i++) {
            res *= i;
            res %= modulo;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println((double)totalTime/1000000000L);
    }

}
```

Comment: Creating a thread is an expensive process, so takes some time to return the benefits.  Try using a ThreadPoolExecutor, and then timing after that's been created ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html )

Comment: @racraman Yes, I'm aware of the overhead that takes creating a thread, I will try using the ThreadPoolExecutor as suggested, however, the code above still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gimape07 that's what comments are for.

Comment: Could you post your "without-thread" version to compare?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your "no thread" (only main thread) version uses all compile time constants which are easier to optimize.

If you make sure the compiler won't know ahead of time what the values will be:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long factorial = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        long modulo = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        long res = 1;
        for(long i = 1; i <= factorial; i++) {
            res *= i;
            res %= modulo;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println((double)totalTime/1000000000L);
    }

}
```

Then it'll be significantly slower:

```
$ java Main 1000000000 1000000007
698611116
11.368487148
```

On my machine, even slightly more so than the 1-thread case of your other one:

```
$ java Main
698611116
10.709532315
```

Similarly, if you modify your 1-thread example to use `.run()` instead of `.start()`, everything will run on the main thread, but there will be no speedup from the 1-thread case.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about those optimizations, can you refer me to a place were I can read more about it?